# Azure SQL Database or SQL Server in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm exploring whether to use Azure SQL Database or SQL Server in Virtual Machine. What are the pros and cons each of them?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...SQL Azure is PaaS, and Sql Server in VM is IaaS. Just to highlight some differences.

1. Control & Features - You got a greater control and features in IaaS where else in PaaS you got to stick with the features they have.
2. Redundancy & Backup - By default, SQL Azure comes with 3 copies of redundancy and you can enable geo-replication to nearest datacenter too. Backup is    automatically done for 7 days and onwards depending on the pricing tier.
3. Cost & Ownership - Basic DB in SQL Azure cost you USD5, however in VM, you can host as many db possible albeit more expensive to rent a single VM.

Check this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/) out to find out more details

Comment: Good answer. Don't forget you need to buy SQL Server for a VM, whereas with SQL Azure it's  'free' (as are upgrades) with the cost of the subscription/usage